# DVD ROM with interactive Uni activities won't install on Ubuntu

Tags: dvd

I have just started an Open Uni degree and been supplied with a DVD ROM which has interactive activities, including video and audio to watch/listen to.  Apparently you have to "install" the DVD and you can then save your progress on each of the activities.  According to the documentation I've been sent, it will only play on Windows and their IT helpdesk can't give any advice about Mac or Linux (dead helpful, thanks).

I only have a laptop with Ubuntu on it.  I do have access to a Windows machine at work but I don't really want to use that unless I absolutely have to for my Uni work.

Other DVDs all work fine.  Can anyone help with the "installation" of this?

I'm not very Linux-savvy unfortunately so I'm just researching as I'm coming across things I can't do.

Thanks in advance.  Clare.

Comment: install wine software center .. or install windows in virtualbox :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell us what degree this is, with possible course code?

The chance is that this DVD is intended for Windows.
Since this is Linux it isn't supported out of the box.
However, Linux has the ability to run Windows software by means of 'WINE', this is a program intended to run Windows software under Linux.

By knowing the course, we can check if it runs well, and tell you how to install it.